# In c++, Insert a vector in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

In c++, I would like to insert a vector in a map.

The key of the map is a pair of string and int, and the value of one is a vector.

I am writing down the following code, however it seems that the vector is not inserted into the map.

Is the syntax of the code is wrong?
If so, could you tell me correct one?

```
map<pair<string, int>, vector<string> > my_map;
vector<string> v;
v.push_back("abcde");
my_map.insert(make_pair(make_pair("aaa",1),v));
```

Comment: Where is `v_pre` defined?

Comment: sorry, it is mistake. I editted.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. [Check it out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cde6a24e38f8cd71)

Comment: Even i am not aable to reproduce the error. Check it : http://ideone.com/XrZYxU

Comment: _"it seems that the vector is not inserted into the map"_ According to.....?

Comment: @ Alejandro, your code goes well.

Comment: @everybody, sorry... it's my mistake. my code was not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the v_pre while vector is of name v:

```
my_map.insert(make_pair(make_pair("aaa",1),v_pre));
```

The correct code should be:

```
my_map.insert(make_pair(make_pair("aaa",1),v));
```

Comment: @szakira: What problem are u getting?

Comment: the value of the map is empty after insert!!

Comment: Check using function my_map.empty(), you will get false.

Comment: for (map<pair<string,int>, vector<string>> ::const_iterator iter1 = my_map.begin();
  iter1 != my_map.end(); iter1++)
 {
  cout << iter1->first.first << endl;
  cout << iter1->first.second << endl;
  cout << iter1->second[0] << endl;
 }

Comment: @everybody, sorry... it's my mistake. my code was not wrong.